# how to convert the temperature from kelvin to Celsius?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix 180*360*120.
120 is time series of temperature in kelvin. now I want to convert this temperature from kelvin to Celsius. kindly suggest me a Matlab code for this conversion.

Comment: maybe http://www.mathworks.com/help/aerotbx/ug/convtemp.html

Answer (score 2):

So what I understand is that you have a matrix A of dimensions 180*360*120 i.e. having 7776000 elements of kelvin temperatures. These Kelvin you want in Celsius. Can you not simply have the following code to get the result?

```
B=A-273.15
where B is your matrix with temperatures in Celsius
```

Comment: thank you for the comments. but I need only the conversion of third dimension which is month in 10 year. that means dimension is having temperature (K) of 120 month.

Comment: Does A(:,:,120)=A(:,:,120)-273.15 satisfy your requirement?